# R regexp for odd sorting of a char vector

Tags: r, regex, sorting

I have several hundred files that need their columns sorted in a convoluted way. Imagine a character vector `x` which is the result of `names(foo)` where `foo` is a `data.frame`:

```
x <- c("x1","i2","Component.1","Component.10","Component.143","Component.13",
       "r4","A","C16:1n-7")
```

I'd like to have it ordered according to the following rule: First, alphabetical for anything starting with "Component". Second, alphabetical for anything remaining starting with "C" and a number. Third anything remaining in alphabetical order.

For `x` that would be:

```
x[c(3,4,6,5,9,8,2,7,1)]
```

Is this a `regexp` kind of task? And does one use `match`? Each file will have a different number of columns (so `x` will be of varying lengths). Any tips appreciated.

Comment: Have a doubt, shouldn't the values with `Component` be correctly ordered i.e. `"Component.1"   "Component.10"  "Component.13"  "Component.143"` or is it just ordered in the order of occurence

Comment: Whoops. Yes. you are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that with the function [`order`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/order) from `base-r`:

```
x <- c("x1","i2","Component.1","Component.10","Component.143","Component.13",
       "r4","A","C16:1n-7")    
order(
    !startsWith(x, "Component"), # 0 - starts with component, 1 - o.w.
    !grepl("^C\\d", x),          # 0 - starts with C<NUMBER>, 1 - o.w.
    x                            # alphabetical
)
# output: 3 4 6 5 9 8 2 7 1
```

Answer (score 1):

We can split int to different elements and then use `mixedsort` from `gtools`

```
v1 <-  c(gtools::mixedsort(grep("Component", x, value = TRUE)), 
  gtools::mixedsort(grep("^C\\d+", x, value = TRUE)))
c(v1, gtools::mixedsort(x[!x %in% v1]))
#[1] "Component.1"   "Component.10"  "Component.13"  "Component.143" "C16:1n-7"      "A"             "i2"            "r4"           
#[9] "x1"
```

---

Or another option in `select` assuming that these are the columns of the data.frame

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  select(mixedsort(starts_with('Component')), 
       mixedsort(names(.)[matches("^C\\d+")]), 
       gtools::mixedsort(names(.)[everything()]))
```

If it is just the order of occurrence

```
df1 %>% 
  select(starts_with('Component'), matches('^C\\d+'), sort(names(.)[everything()]))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(5 * 9), ncol = 9,
         dimnames = list(NULL, x)))
```

Comment: Your third regex will leave out strings starting with C that didn't match the first two, e.g. "Cxx".

Answer (score 1):

A brute-force solution using only base R:

```
first = sort(x[grepl('^Component', x)])
second = sort(x[grepl('^C\\d', x)])
third = sort(setdiff(x, c(first, second)))
c(first, second, third)
```